# Profiling of Python threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to figure out how to measure the performance of several python threads in my application. I currently have several tasks that are executing on different threads based on user input and I would like to measure the execution time, maybe even memory consumption of each of the threads. I have tried to use cProfile (on each instantiation of the thread, then I would write the data to a file and then aggregate all results) with limited success. Also, I have an added problem of having some blocking IO which is skewing my results. Is there anyway to effectively profile my application?

Comment: By using cProfile, you've made a great start! If you could explain a little more about your "limited success" with cProfile, we could probably help fix that and continue from there.

Comment: As an unrelated note, you might want to consider multiple processes instead of multiple threads: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different ways to tackle this problem. `cProfile` is great and comes with Python, however many people see multi-threaded profiling as an issue. One way of getting around this is by running separate instances of cProfile for each thread and then combining the results using `Stats.add`.

Should that not be as useful as you'd hoped, another alternative could be to use [Yappi](http://code.google.com/p/yappi/), which I've had success using for a few special multi-threaded cases. It's got great documentation so you shouldn't have too much trouble setting it up.

For memory specific profiling, check out [Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy). But be warned, it may create some of the largest log files you've ever seen if your code is bad!

Comment: My system is a web server, if I use `pr = cProfile.Profile()` in different request, is it so called **separate instances of cProfile** ?