# Proflie multi-thread python application

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, yappi

I'm using Pycharm IDE on a multi thread python application. I tried the default `cProfile` and the `yappi` but cannot get results for threads other than the main thread. I'm using python 3.6.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the go to approach for persistent threads is to run a cprofile instance per thread, then combine the results, better explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2218592/9981387

Comment: I don't understand how to use this in Pycharm and this is why I asked. Currently I cannot get neither the cProfile nor the yappi to work on Pycharm.